# Origen de la palabra "coco"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Parece que está bastante aceptado (Corominas lo recoge así en su diccionario etimológico) que el fruto del cocotero debe su nombre a cierto fantasma que aterra a los niños:

> **[coco<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9bCoA8r%7C9bH8Cra%7C9bIHCql%7C9bJM96n)**
>
> De *coco*<sup>2</sup>, porque la cáscara del fruto con sus tres agujeros semeja una cabeza con ojos y boca, como la de aquel fantasma infantil.
>
> **coco<sup>2</sup>**
>
> Del port. *côco*, fantasma que lleva una calabaza vacía, a modo de cabeza.

La palabra *coco* con el significado de "ser imaginario con que se mete miedo a los niños" o "gesto, mueca" se usa en español desde mediados del siglo XV, y en portugués al menos desde principios del mismo siglo. Antes de eso también se registra la palabra *coco* pero con otro significado:

> **coco<sup>3</sup>**
>
> Del lat. *coccum*, y este del gr. *κόκκος kókkos*.
>
> 1. m. Zool. **gorgojo** (‖ insecto).

De hecho el primer diccionario que recoge la palabra es el de Percival de 1591:

> Coco, a worme that eateth vines.

Pero me estoy desviando. Parece que la palabra *coco* entonces viene del portugués, pero ¿se sabe algo más acerca de su origen? Corominas dice simplemente que es una voz infantil de creación expresiva. ¿Hay alguna otra teoría?

Answer (score 2):

Hay algo de información en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611. Con respecto al fruto del coco nos confirma la etimología:

> El nombre de coco se le dieron los Españoles, por el gestillo que se figura con los tres agugeros, que parecen ojos y boca:

Pero a continuación viene algo interesante:

> en razón de que ordinariamente llamamos coco una postura de rostro, qual la tiene la mona, quando da a entender estar enojada, y haze un sonido en la garganta de Ko Ko, de donde se tomò el nombre de coco, y cocar.

Efectivamente, en el mismo diccionario de Covarrubias se define (y la expresión [continúa en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9YWIVl4) a día de hoy):

> COCAR, y hazer cocos, està tomado del sonido que haze la mona para espantar los muchachos, y ponerlos miedo, porque no lo hagan mal.

Una leve referencia a las posibles muecas de los monos se encuentra también en la etimología propuesta para [*coco* en Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/coco):

> [...] from Spanish and Portuguese coco "grinning or grimacing face," on resemblance of the three depressions at the base of the shell to a monkey or human face.

Comment: yo había escuchado que coco es como se les dice a los duendes en portugués, pero no he encontrado ninguna fuente que valide esto, que es la forma de tres agujeros y una  protuberancia  (ojos, boca y nariz) es la cara de un duende o la cara del coco